# What view does Devise Registrations#create controller render if using JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I have the following `devise` routes in a Rails app under an `api` namespace that returns JSON:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do 
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'api/sessions', 
    registrations: 'api/registrations'
    }  
end
```

When I hit `registrations#create`, I want to be able to customize the JSON returned instead of the default given by Devise. Which view do I need to override, and how?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a block in a custom controller.

```
class Api::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 

    respond_to :json

    def create
        super do
            render "api/users/show" and return
        end
    end

    def resource_name
        :user
    end
end
```